# POJO object to JSON Object conversion in java

Tags: java, spring

My requirement is needed to convert POJO OR DTO Object into JSON Format, I have used below methodology

```java
JsonObject obj = gson.toJsonTree(pojo class).getAsJsonObject();
for (String key: obj.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(" key is " + key + " value  is " + obj.get(key));
}
```

But with this i am getting key data as string(eg:"employee"), so if i insert this data in database it inserting with double quotes("employee") only.

Comment: So the problem is not with json conversion but with storing it in the database?

Comment: yes, it is storing in database as string,JsonObject obj= new JsonObject(gson.toJson(object_need))
by looping obj i am getting proper data. by using this code by problem resolved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it easily by using third party libraries like ***[Jackson](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html)*** or ***[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)*** to serialize and deserialize objects.

> Jackson:
>   Reference code snippet:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = new User();

//Object to JSON in file
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), user);

//Object to JSON in String
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
```

You can find detailed info from [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

> Gson: Reference code snippet

```
User user = new User();
Gson gson = new Gson();

// Object to JSON in String
String json = gson.toJson(object_need);
```

For detailed usages as reference:

- **[Jackson](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)**
- **[Gson](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)**

But it seems like the main problem here is you have a problem at inserting the serialized data to DB and to solve that you need to give more information about the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your update , is there anyway by using gson library,instead of jackson library because ,in my project don't have jackson library for this single requirement i can't add jackson jar file in my project.

Comment: I answered regarding to title of the question. Since there is no information given about the issue for storing data on DB, I editted my answer to request more information from the OP